# Randomly select rows from a table based on weight and probability

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL. I have a table which looks like that:

`id: primary key
name: varchar
weight: int (this can be either 1,2 or 3)`

What I want to do is randomly select one row until I get a list of 400 selected rows from a table similar to that below that has 500 rows, but taking into account the weight. 

`For example, if I have 3 rows:
id, name, weight
1, "some content", 2
2, "other content", 1
3, "something", 3`

When creating the list, rows that have a weight of 2 appear 30% of times in the list, rows that have a weight of 1 appear 20% of times in the list and rows with weight of 3 appear 50% of times in the list.

Duplicates are permitted but not back to back.

Is there a way to do that?

If you don't understand something please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is better. So on the list of 400, 200 will be weight 3, and if there isnt 200 on the 500 pool just use duplicated?

Comment: `ORDER BY weight * RAND() DESC LIMIT 400` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes out of the 400, 200 selections would have weight 3, 120 would be weight 2 and 80 will be weight 1. Speaking of weight 3 if their are no more new weight 3s to make up the 200 then randomly pick an existing weight 3 even if it has be chosen before. The same would go for the other weights

Comment: @eggyal that wont provide the desire ratios.

Comment: If the weight column contained `20`, `30` and `50` instead of `1`, `2` and `3` then the expectation would be random results in the desired ratios—though obviously it won't force the desired ratios through repetition etc... that doesn't strike me as something SQL would be well-suited to accomplishing.

Comment: One *could* achieve repetition through `UNION`, but in the worst case (e.g. only 1 record with weight `3`) one would need 200 `UNION`s!  (Actually the *worst* case would be *no* records with weight `3`—it's not at all clear how that should be handled).

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  What is the actual business problem you're trying to solve by adopting this approach?  Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: There will always be weighted values as they are manually entered. So 3,2 and 1 will appear at least once for sure. It is to accomplish choosing newer content over older ones.3 being newest 1 oldest

Comment: "*It is to accomplish choosing newer content over older ones*"—merely sorting by publication date would accomplish that.  You clearly have other requirements that you're not mentioning.  Why, for example, would anyone want to see 200 copies of the same content simply because it's the only one with weight 3?

Comment: The weights are user generated so they may have a reason for wanting to have some content show more than others. For one we have a festival and we prefer music from that festival show up more than other newer content.

Answer (score 1):

I still havent solve the repetition part. But this will give you a start

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5372e/23)**

- most inner select assign a random number
- middle select use variables to assign a row_number to each row partition by Weight
- last select filter to match the ratio. In this case generate a list of size 50.
- the original data has an evenly distribution of ~30 for each category. So size 60 will be the limit to achive `50% Weight = 3`

.

```
SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`Weight`, RowNumber
FROM ( 
        SELECT *,
                @row_num := IF(@prev_value = `Weight`,
                               @row_num + 1,
                               IF(@prev_value:=`Weight`,
                                  1,
                                  1)
                               ) AS RowNumber
        FROM (                                                      
              SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`Weight`,  rand() as rng
              FROM      `myTable`              
              ORDER BY `Weight`, rng
             ) X  
        CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @row_num := 1, @prev_value := 0) y
     ) T     
WHERE ( Weight = 3 and RowNumber <= 50 * 0.5 )
   OR ( Weight = 2 and RowNumber <= 50 * 0.3 )
   OR ( Weight = 1 and RowNumber <= 50 * 0.2 )
ORDER BY Weight, RowNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make a temporary table where all records with 1's are repeated 2 times, alle records with 2 are repeated 3 times, and all records with  3's are repeated 5 times. Then make random selections in the temporary table among all the records. This should statistically end up with a distribution very near your target, if the total is large enough (e.g. 400).

Comment: What if there are fewer than 40 records in the original table with any given weight?  Then repeating only 2, 3 and 5 times would yield insufficient records overall in the termporary table.

Comment: Moreover, uniformly random selection from the temporary table wouldn't guarantee results in the desired ratios.  It's possible, for example, that only records with weight 1 and 2 happen to be selected.

Comment: If you allow for duplicates (If I understand you correctly), then you could use larger multipliers but with same ratio, eg. 5, 10, 25.

Comment: When you use random selection, there is always the chance that you will get fringe (skewed) selections. That is the nature of randomness. If you have large enough numbers, you will get close. If  you require that you have an exact distribution, then it is not random (which is what you stated as a requirement in your question). "What I want to do is randomly select one row ..."

Comment: It doesn't need to be exact but close 2 as I know the results would only suit specific numbers

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer I solve how assign an ID to each weight. Here I will show you how create a list to handle the duplicates.

I use tables to show the whole process, also you can do select on the demo to validate each result. But with some work can be combine in a single query but wont be easy to read.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b10a3/8)**

First we need to create a table to store which row will participate in your list

```
CREATE TABLE `incr` (
   `weight` mediumint,
   `row` mediumint
);
```

Using store procedure we fill the table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile(IN Size INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT Size * 0.5;

  WHILE v1 >= 0 DO
    IF v1 <= (Size - 1) * 0.5 THEN       
        INSERT incr VALUES (3, v1);
    END IF;
    IF v1 <= (Size - 1) * 0.3 THEN
        INSERT incr VALUES (2, v1);
    END IF;
    IF v1 <= (Size - 1) * 0.2 THEN
        INSERT incr VALUES (1, v1);
    END IF;

    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END//

CALL dowhile(300); -- Indicate List Size
```

Now create a new table to know the size of each weight category in our sample.

```
CREATE TABLE maxWeight 
      SELECT `Weight`, COUNT(*) as mw 
      FROM `myTable`
      GROUP BY `Weight`;
```

Using `%` operator we can repeat the rows to fill the required size

```
CREATE TABLE rowList
      SELECT i.weight,
             CASE WHEN i.row >= w.mw then i.row % w.mw
                  ELSE i.row
             END newrow
      FROM incr i
      JOIN maxWeight w
        ON i.weight = w.weight;
```

As you can see here even when my list is only 100 the final result is 300

```
SELECT weight, count(*)
FROM rowList
GROUP BY weight;

| weight | count(*) |
|--------|----------|
|      1 |       60 |
|      2 |       90 |
|      3 |      150 |
```

Now join both tables together

```
CREATE TABLE finalResult
      SELECT `ID`,`Name`, T.`Weight`, RowNumber
      FROM ( 
              SELECT *,
                      @row_num := IF(@prev_value = `Weight`,
                                     @row_num + 1,
                                     IF(@prev_value:=`Weight`,
                                        0,
                                        0)
                                     ) AS RowNumber
              FROM (                                                      
                    SELECT `ID`,`Name`,`Weight`,  rand() as rng
                    FROM      `myTable`              
                    ORDER BY `Weight`, rng
                   ) X  
              CROSS JOIN  (SELECT @row_num := 0, @prev_value := 0) y
           ) T   
      JOIN  rowList
        ON T.`RowNumber` = rowList.`newrow`
       AND T.`Weight` = rowList.`weight`;
```

The final result has the desire ratio using repeat the names

```
SELECT `Weight`, COUNT(*) total, COUNT(DISTINCT `Name`) d_name
FROM finalResult
GROUP BY `Weight`;    


| Weight | total | d_name |
|--------|-------|--------|
|      1 |    60 |     36 |
|      2 |    90 |     32 |
|      3 |   150 |     30 |
```

Even when original table has 37 `weight = 1`, the tool I use to generate random values duplicate one Name, so `d_name = 36`